# How to understand "otherwise experience very largely" in the Sapir-Whorf Hypothesis?

Tags: english, philosophy-of-language

I’m a Chinese and can’t understand a classic text from *The Status Of Linguistics As A Science* (1929) by Edward Sapir.

> We see and hear and **otherwise experience very largely** as we do because the language habits of our community predispose certain choices of interpretation.

A commonly seen Chinese translation for “otherwise” here is “using other methods”, so the Chinese translation for the sentence says: Everything we see, hear or experience using other methods is very largely because the language habits of our community predispose certain choices of interpretation.

I don’t quite agree with the translation. My understanding is, “otherwise” here mean “differently”; “see and hear” are the senses, while “experience” is a comprehensive feeling obtained through seeing, hearing, tasting, touching and any other sense.
My understanding can be expressed like this: We see and hear, but we have very largely different experience as we see and hear, because…

Please help me analyze the sentence and tell me whether my understanding is correct. Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I put it here mainly because it's about liguistic determinism. I guess the forum can help me find out its meaning, and thus I can modify my intepretation. It's OK to remove it if it's not appropriate.

Comment: I believe this is a valid question for this site. Although it is, indeed, about parsing an English sentence, it is focussed on the *interpretation of an academic book* (a book of Linguistics). Considering that many of us are not native English speakers, this question and its answers could help many readers in the future.

Comment: I don't think it's a great question for this site. I'm happy it was answered, I even voted it up since it's obviously in good faith, but I don't think it would be very useful for others just based on the fact it's from a linguistics book: there are many of those, they contain tons of paragraphs like this one, they are in many languages other than English too, nevermind the amount of "academic" books in general... Are questions about all of that going to be allowed, even when specifically linguistics terms are not involved? I think this question would be better off on an English-specific site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence parses as follows:

> { We { { see } and { hear } and { ( otherwise ) experience } } ( ( very largely ) as we do ) }
>   because
>   { { the language habits of our community } predispose { certain choices of interpretation } }.

That is, (otherwise) adverbially modifies "experience". We have three verb phrases in conjunction, "see" and "hear" and "otherwise experience". Your interpretation is incorrect; "otherwise experience" here means "experience besides seeing or hearing". The sentence can be phrased in more simple English as:

> We experience things (including seeing and hearing and other experiences) in the way that we do, very largely because our community has habits of language that give us a tendency to choose certain interpretations of those experiences.

Note that in my simple rephrasing I chose to have "very largely" modify "because", because it means essentially the same thing as the original. The original says that most of our experiences (very largely what we see, hear or otherwise experience) are the way they are because of XXX. My rephrasing says that our experiences are the way they are mostly (very largely) because of XXX. The grammatical construction is different, but the meaning is very largely the same, so the simple rephrasing is preferable for clear communication.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you that "otherwise" adverbially modifies "experience", but in my opinion, "very largely" also modifies "experience", not modifying "because...".

Comment: And I think "see" and "hear" are senses, which are different from "experience" here. This text is to say, we see and hear the same world, but because of language, we have different experiences of the world, or different worldview.

Comment: @wajing: I am a native English speaker, and you are simply wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep your analysis in mind though "native speaker" only can't convince me, because some native speakers think  my opinion makes sense to them.

Comment: @wajing: It is true that native speakers will disagree on some aspects of the language, but that is partly because some of them have lower proficiency than others. For example, some less educated people write "could of" instead of "could have", and in some regions people say "have dove" instead of "have dived". Everyone is free to speak and write as they please, but how they do so will influence whether or not they are perceived to have mastery of the English language.

Comment: @wajing "otherwise" and "very largely" may both modify "experience", but that doesn't mean you can turn "otherwise" into "differently" and make "very largely" apply to it even though it comes *after* it and is definitely *not* modifying that part. I am not even a native speaker, if that helps more. I'm just pretty sure I'm right.

Comment: @user21820 I can't understand why "very largely" is put behind "experience" if the author wants to say it's "very largely because". He could organize it as "...otherwise experience as we do very largely because". And thank you so much for your patience and explanation. I'll go back to accept your answer when I fully understand the sentence. :)

Comment: @wajing: I will edit to explain why both mean the same thing despite "very largely" modifying different parts of the sentence.

Comment: @LjL Thank you. But how to intepret "otherwise experience very largely"? I got a suggestion from wordreference.com that "Otherwise" is best interpreted as "in different ways", and it means to experience in different ways than just seeing and hearing.

Comment: @wajing: I already answered that earlier: *Your interpretation is incorrect; "otherwise experience" here means "experience besides seeing or hearing".*

Comment: @user21820 I think I fully understand the sentence after reading your newly edited one and the comments. Yes, I was wrong. It's so happy to say that. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @wajing personally I would have written "very largely because" instead of separating "very largely" from "because", for clarity, but the original sentence is fine too. There are cases in English where word order is flexible, and others where it isn't. Sadly they have to be recognized individually. To reinforce what user21820 said, I can see at once that "otherwise" here is to be understood as a kind of clarifying connective (if you said "see, hear or experience" I could ask "isn't seeing and hearing a kind of experiencing?"): it underlines that seeing and hearing are kinds of experiencing.

Comment: I agree completely with @LjL that "sadly [cases where word order is flexible] have to be recognized individually". One could probably write n rules that apply to all except 1/n of the cases. =P